# Ionic 2 nav bar title and left and right button issue

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using ionic 2. And I am making the navbar as title as centre . and one left and right button with some onclick function. I got some solution that will keep the title as centre. But the left and right button are not in proper way. It's like vertical one by one. But I need horizontally. I tried lot but not able to get that?

Here's my code :

**My scss :**

```
ion-header {
  .button-md {
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  .toolbar-title {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
}
```

**my html :**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-toolbar>



    <ion-buttons >
    <button ion-button class="loginnavbtn" (click)="goback()" left>Save</button>

    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-title>
      LOGIN
    </ion-title>

    <ion-buttons >
    <button ion-button class="loginnavbtn" (click)="goback()" right>Save</button>

    </ion-buttons>


  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>


   </ion-content>
```

The output that i need:

```
**cancel     LOGIN       Save**
```

But the output i am getting :

[image]

I applied some css to make my button to move right, but it increasing whole navbar height .

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to add the `ion-buttons start` and `end`

```
<ion-buttons start>
  <button ion-button class="loginnavbtn" (click)="goback()" left>Save</button>
</ion-buttons>

<ion-title>
  LOGIN
</ion-title>

<ion-buttons end>
  <button ion-button class="loginnavbtn" (click)="goback()" right>Save</button>
</ion-buttons>
```